# train keras applications from scratch in tensorflow 2

Tags: tensorflow, keras

For benchmarking different Frameworks, I want to train a inception v3 network from scratch.
Here the code snippet to build the model:

```
IMAGE_RES = 229
NUM_CLASSES = 102
model = tf.keras.applications.InceptionV3(include_top=True,weights=None,classes=NUM_CLASSES)
model.build(input_shape=(None, IMAGE_RES , IMAGE_RES , channels))
```

according to the official keras website, the argument `weight=None` , means a random initialization. Does this mean that I am training my network from scratch? If not, how is it possible to train the nerwork from scratch?

Comment: why use `model. build`? Are you plan to train the model with a custom training loop something from scratch?

Comment: I am new to tensorflow/keras, I dont want to build a custom training loop. Does this mean that model.build() is not necessray?

Comment: When you set `wegiht=None` you're training the model from scratch. Also, if you load the weight and don't freeze it, it also means you're training from scratch but this time you've initialized wight some optimized parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it means that you are training your model from scratch.

Weight and biases in deep learning models are randomly initialized following some specific shemes. (See the Xavier Glorot scheme for example) Those schemes generally helps the network converge faster and achieves better results, by preventing the gradient to either vanish or explode, and by maintaining a low variance in the gradient across all layers.